Is there a Block Based IDE for ESP32 that is still maintained in 2024?
I am trying to work on Block-Based Robot programming with my daughter using ESP32-WROOM-32D. I can get everything working with Platform.io but she is used to using Block Programming. I took a look at a few of the offerings and most seem to be last updated 4 years ago. There is one called CodeSkool that seems to be the go to but it seems to be out of date as well and tries to open a WS connection from a HTTPS connection which doesn't work in modern browsers.
Does anyone know if there is a Block-Based IDE that is currently maintained and supports ESP32?

This question isn't about which one to use it is about which one is still being supported. Multiple answers can be included. This is not "This question is seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources"

You are looking for recommendations for tools, specifically one that is a block-based IDE and is maintained and supports ESP32.

That isnt true I know them I just want to know if one is maintained. If that was true I wouldnt have listed one this makes no sense

"if one is maintained" would fall into "other off-site resources".
